# REST API call to get the list of SQL databases from Azure

Tags: bash, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to make a call using Azure REST API to get the list of databases and delete the particular database if exits.

If somebody could give me a shell script that would be helpful. I tried this to list Azure SQL Databases on a given server

```
wget -U --no-check-certificate    https://management.core.windows.net:8443/  subscriptionID/services/sqlservers/servers/serverName/p1y/databases? contentview=generic
--2016-01-22 22:15:57--     https://management.core.windows.net:8443/${subscriptionID}/services/sqlservers/s    ervers/${serverName}/databases?contentview=generic
Resolving management.core.windows.net (management.core.windows.net)...xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to management.core.windows.net (management.core.windows.net)|xx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:8443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-01-22 22:15:57 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use cURL instead of wget. But, before you use cURL, you need to create and upload a certificate.

First, you need to install openssl and curl in your machine. And then you can create a .pem file with the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout azure-cert.pem -out azure-cert.pem
```

Note: openssl will ask you to input a lot of things.

this is for local usage. From the .pem file, you can create a .cer file which will be uploaded to Azure. Use the following command to create one.

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in azure-cert.pem -out azure-cert.cer
```

Go the the classic portal of Azure, in the **Management certificates** page of **Settings**, click upload, and choose the .cer file created above.

Wait for a few seconds, and after the certificate is created, you can use the following command to get a list of SQL Database in some SQL server.

```
curl -E azure-cert.pem -H "x-ms-version: 2011-10-01" "https://management.core.windows.net:8443/{subscriptionId}/services/sqlservers/servers/{serverName}/databases?contentview=generic"
```

If you want to delete an SQL Database, you can use the following command.

```
curl -X DELETE -E azure-cert.pem -H "x-ms-version: 2011-10-01" "https://management.core.windows.net:8443/{subscriptionId}/services/sqlservers/servers/{serverName}/databases/{databaseName}"
```

The output of these commands are XML code which is hard to read. So, I recommend you to use Azure CLI instead. But, if you insist, and need more information about cURL with HTTP Jobs, see [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Modify_method_and_headers). If you need more information about Azure REST API, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt420159.aspx)

Comment: For deleting the database I can use the curl command directly right? this doesnot need the output in readable form.

Comment: Yes. For a simple deletion operation, no need to read those XML. Actually, The deletion return nothing at all. But, for debugging, reading XML is going to be a nightmare. I'm not sure your purpose of this. If just automating those operations, I strongly recommend you to use Azure CLI. Unless, you want to reuse some previous written codes which involve with XML, and those codes are hard to modify.

Comment: Thankyou so much it works for me, I am not allowed to install azure cli tool on the server, I know azure cli makes my work very easy :(                              I have one more question when i provide the cert.pem path it doesnot work if i curl it from the cert.pem location it work, How do i use the command if i want to provide the path like                                                             "curl -X DELETE -E /etc/ssl/azure-cert.pem .....

Comment: Make sure the current user have permission to the location of your .pem file. (For example, in Ubuntu, try the command with `sudo`.) I tried it at my end. It works with absolute path. If is not a problem of permission, please provide the error message, so that I can further investigate.

Comment: ` sudo curl -E /etc/ssl/private/prod.pem -H "x-ms-version: 2011-10-01" "https://management.core.windows.net:8443/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/s ervices/sqlservers/servers/xxxxxxx/databases?contentview=generic"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>`

Comment: Sorry it is working I messedup in the URL. Thankyou so much :)

Comment: This is a HTTP Error 400, with message "The request is badly formed". This is usually caused by a whitespace in your url. I can see a space in `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/s ervices/`. I don't know whether it's a copy-and-paste problem, or something else. Please make sure your url is correct.

Comment: If nothing else need to be clarified, please mark my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to get list of Azure sql databases with only subscription ID?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the list of all sql databases with one request. But, you can get the list of sql servers using [this request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505702.aspx). And then, you can loop through each server, and get the list of sql databases.

Comment: Thankyou @Jack Zeng, Could you see this link, I have asked another question could give some idea about it. Link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028728/script-to-delete-azure-sql-database-if-servername-is-null`

Comment: I need some info on Azure SQL backup, I know Azure SQL has auto backup, A guy from my team asked me Is it possible to delete existing AZURE backup,If yes who will have access to delete it.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Azure has an built-in service that allows you to restore your database to a point in time. The service is free, and not possible to disable (and no reason to disable it). I think this is what you said the "auto backup". There is another backup strategy -- geo-replication which is for disaster restoration. If you want to delete a geo-replication, just login the [classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) > **SQL Database** > **<your database>** > **geo-replication**, select the geo-replication you want to delete, and click **Stop Secondary**

Comment: There is another strategy -- export database to a file. This strategy may backup your database to a blob in a storage account (as a ".dacpac" file). You can try in [classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) > **SQL Databases** > **<your database>** > **Export** (at the bottom). To delete this kind of backup, you need to know the storage account and the container. Again, you can delete it in [classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/)  > **Storage** > **<your storage account>** > **Containers** > **<your container>** > **<your .dacpac file>** > **Delete** (at the bottom).